# Problem connecting Mysql database with docker Keycloak

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, keycloak

compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=mysql
      - DB_ADDR=address
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - DISABLED_EXTENSIONS=org.keycloak.keycloak-oidc-keycloak-json-logger
    ports:
      - 8588:8080


  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and also a Dockerfile:

```
# Use the base Keycloak image
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest

# Set environment variables
ENV KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin

# Disable Metrics subsystem
RUN sed -i '/<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:metrics:.*$/,/<\/subsystem>/d' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/sta>

# Expose the Keycloak port
EXPOSE 8080
```

So when I do the docker-compose up it  builds me correct the keycloak inside my database and updates it with the default columns of the keycloak but when I go to the logs it gets me some errors:

```
13:20:15,230 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "metrics")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MetricsSubsystemAdd.java:91)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1040)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:779)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:459)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:412)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

13:20:15,235 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
13:20:15,252 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0403: Unexpected failure during execution of the following operation(s): [{
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
    ],
    "operation" => "add",
    "map-groups-to-roles" => false
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm"),
        ("authentication" => "local")
    ],
    "default-user" => "$local",
    "skip-group-loading" => true
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm"),
        ("authentication" => "properties")
    ],
    "path" => "mgmt-users.properties",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm"),
        ("authorization" => "properties")
    ],
    "path" => "mgmt-groups.properties",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
}, {
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
    ],
    "operation" => "add"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm"),
        ("server-identity" => "ssl")
    ],
    "keystore-path" => "application.keystore",
    "keystore-relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir",
    "keystore-password" => "password",
    "alias" => "server",
    "key-password" => "password",
    "generate-self-signed-certificate-host" => "localhost"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm"),
        ("authentication" => "local")
    ],
    "default-user" => "$local",
    "allowed-users" => "*",
    "skip-group-loading" => true
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm"),
        ("authentication" => "properties")
    ],
    "path" => "application-users.properties",
    "relative-to" => "jboss.server.config.dir"
}, {
    "operation" => "add",
    "address" => [
        ("core-service" => "management"),
        ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm"),
        ("authorization" => "properties")
    ],
```

and these:

```
13:13:35,724 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
13:13:40,726 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@5b09417d for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1513)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1496)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1360)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:912)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:762)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:459)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:412)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

13:13:40,727 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@5b09417d for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Anyone got any idea what the issue is? As I figured out it maybe doesnt connect with the environment of the keycloak but as u can see all the credentials are the same